# Scala SBT and scala-library.jar file inclusion

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

When I try to including `scala jar` in my `java server` application I get error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

It means I need to include `scala-library.jar` in my `CLASSPATH` 
Is there any way that sbt build process will include this in the `target` jars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sbt-assembly plugin is the answer. It'll produce a fat jar that includes all your dependencies.